# razor syntax confusion if / then

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a code block that works fine

```
@foreach (var message in Model.OrderBy(a => a.messageOrder))
{
    if ((DateTime.Compare(message.messageStart, DateTime.Now) < 0) && 
      (DateTime.Compare(message.messageEnd, DateTime.Now) > 0))
    {

    if (!message.hideHeader)
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", message.headerClass, 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.headerHTML)) ? message.header : 
         Server.HtmlDecode(message.headerHTML)));
    }
    switch (message.numColumns)
    {
        case 1:
            @Html.Partial("_contentBlock", message)
            break;
        default:
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Partial("_contentBlock", message)
            </div>
            break;
    }
}
}
```

but i tried putting a div around this code based on an if/then and can't get the razor syntax correct. in Visual Studio intellisence does not highlight from the if (!message.hideHeader) on.  Not getting any errors -

```
@foreach (var message in Model.OrderBy(a => a.messageOrder))
{
    if ((DateTime.Compare(message.messageStart, DateTime.Now) < 0) && 
    (DateTime.Compare(message.messageEnd, DateTime.Now) > 0))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.msgClass))
    {
        <div class="@message.msgClass">
    }
    if (!message.hideHeader)
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", message.headerClass, (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.headerHTML)) ? message.header : Server.HtmlDecode(message.headerHTML)));
    }
    switch (message.numColumns)
    {
        case 1:
            @Html.Partial("_contentBlock", message)
            break;
        default:
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Partial("_contentBlock", message)
            </div>
            break;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.msgClass))
    {
        </div>
    }
}
}
```

any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix the HTML markup within the code block with `@:`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.msgClass))
{
    @:<div class="@message.msgClass">
}

<!-- some other code goes here -->

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.msgClass))
{
    </div>
}
```

The `@:` tells the compiler that it is the start of a HTML block inside a C# code block.

Comment: I used             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.msgClass))
        {
           @:</div>
        }   and that seems to work.. Thank you!